# What is the biggest margin with which a team has won an NBA game?

Tags: basketball, nba

What is the biggest margin with which a team has won an NBA game ?

Comment: I've reopened this - but also downvoted it as I believe it is a poor question. The tooltip for downvoting a question says "This question does not show any research effort", and this question currently clearly falls into that category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easily searched for:

The biggest margin in the history of the NBA is **68** and was achieved in 1991, when the Cleveland Cavaliers beat Miami Heat with **148-80** ([game report](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/199112170CLE.html)). In there is also a link to [this page](https://www.basketball-reference.com/leaders/team_pts.html#all_team-largest-mov-game) showing lots of other NBA records. [Here](https://www.landofbasketball.com/statistics/largest_margins.htm) is another source.